# How to show scroll bar in the text area in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I am learning Java.I just created an application (liked desktop one in c#) by adding some labels,a text view and a button.
Its fun learning this new thing,but i soon encountered an issue ,when u tried to add vertical scrolling to the text view i added on the UI.

I also tried adding vertical scroll to the text area but still my text area is not displaying the scroll bar.

The part of the code created when i added the controls from the panel to the UI is as below:

```
thisLayout.setVerticalGroup(thisLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(17, 17)

                .addComponent(getJtxtArea(), GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 158, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
```

The code for the function getJtxtArea() is as below:

```
private JTextArea getJtxtArea() {
        if(jtxtArea == null) {
            jtxtArea = new JTextArea();
            jtxtArea.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,255,255));
            jtxtArea.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI",3,14));
            jtxtArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            jtxtArea.setLineWrap(true);
            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(jtxtArea);
            scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            }
            return jtxtArea;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why i am not getting the scroll bar on the text view.Thanks in advance.

**Note:I am using Eclipse Helios as the IDE and using Jigloo plugin in eclipse for the GUI.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the component `scroll` instead of the jtxtArea. In addition to that, you might also want to resize your JScrollPane.

Comment: hi michael ,thanks for the quick reply ,i added the scroll instead of jtxtArea like this

Comment: .addComponent(scroll, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 158, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)

Comment: But its giving me exception java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Comment: you might want to change the private JTextArea getJtxtArea() to return the scroll. private JScrollPane getScroll() and return your scroll.

Comment: Now i can see the scroll bar in the text area but contents are not displayed in the text area now

Comment: What do you mean by contents?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22168/discussion-between-vipin-nair-and-michael-ardan)

Comment: hi you there?Have to ask you something

Comment: hi i need to create a window service of my java application .i tried using java service wrapper but i am not getting it